# Binding to the ViewModel not working in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to make an app that shows a list of countries, when a country is clicked it shows a list of cities that are in that country.

Country.cs:

```
public class Country {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
  public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

City.cs:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Navigation is performed in CountryPageViewModel.cs through:

```
async void OnSelectedCountry(Country country)
    {
        if (country == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(CitiesPage)}?{nameof(CitiesViewModel.Name)}={country.Name}");
    }
```

Cities are loaded into the CitiesViewModel.cs:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Name), nameof(Name))]
public class CitiesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string countryName;

    public IList<City> CityList { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return countryName;
        }

        set
        {
            countryName = value;
            LoadCities(value);
        }
    }

    public async void LoadCities(string countryName)
    {
        try
        {
            Country country = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(cityName);
            IList<City> cities = country.Cities;
            CityList = cities;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Impossible to load cities");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the XAML (CitiesPage.xaml):

```
<CollectionView x:Name="citiesCollectionView"  x:DataType="viewmodels:CitiesViewModel"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}"
            EmptyView="Impossible to load cities" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="5" x:DataType="models:City">
                <Frame Style="{StaticResource CityCard}">
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
                          ColumnDefinitions="Auto" >
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                            Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Padding="10"
                            HeightRequest="50" />
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

But nothing is showing up in the Cities page. I've set BindingContext in the CitiesPage.xaml.cs (code behind) to the ViewModel.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: none of your setters appear to call `PropertyChanged`.  And the code in `LoadCities` appears to reference several undefined variables.  Is that a cut/paste error, or is the actual code like that?  Have you debugged it to verify that data is loaded?

Comment: Undefined variables in `LoadCities` are cut/paste error as I was trying to translate them in English, `regione` stands for `Country` in the code.
Which setters do I need to modify and add `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: you are binding to `CityList` so you need to raise `PropertyChanged` when it is set

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your time, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who may have same problem, as xamarin document says

> All view model and model classes that are accessible to a view should
> implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Implementing this
> interface in a view model or model class allows the class to provide
> change notifications to any data-bound controls in the view when the
> underlying property value changes.

Here are more tips about **PropertyChanged:**

> -Always raising a PropertyChanged event if a public property's value
> changes. Do not assume that raising the PropertyChanged event can be
> ignored because of knowledge of how XAML binding occurs.

> Always raising a PropertyChanged event for any calculated properties whose
> values are used by other properties in the view model or model.

> Always raising the PropertyChanged event at the end of the method that makes
> a property change, or when the object is known to be in a safe state.
> Raising the event interrupts the operation by invoking the event's
> handlers synchronously. If this happens in the middle of an operation,
> it might expose the object to callback functions when it is in an
> unsafe, partially updated state. In addition, it's possible for
> cascading changes to be triggered by PropertyChanged events. Cascading
> changes generally require updates to be complete before the cascading
> change is safe to execute.

> Never raising a PropertyChanged event if
> the property does not change. This means that you must compare the old
> and new values before raising the PropertyChanged event.

> Never raising
> the PropertyChanged event during a view model's constructor if you are
> initializing a property. Data-bound controls in the view will not have
> subscribed to receive change notifications at this point.

> Never
> raising more than one PropertyChanged event with the same property
> name argument within a single synchronous invocation of a public
> method of a class. For example, given a NumberOfItems property whose
> backing store is the _numberOfItems field, if a method increments
> _numberOfItems fifty times during the execution of a loop, it should only raise property change notification on the NumberOfItems property
> once, after all the work is complete. For asynchronous methods, raise
> the PropertyChanged event for a given property name in each
> synchronous segment of an asynchronous continuation chain.